# Cassandra Query Timeout with small set of data

Tags: cassandra

I am having a problem with Cassandra 2.1.17.  I have a table with about 40k "rows" in it.  One partition I am having a problem with has maybe about 5k entries in it.

Table is:

```
create table billing (
    accountid uuid,
    date timeuuid,
    credit double,
    debit double,
    type text,
    primary key (accountid,date)
) with clustering order by (date desc)
```

So there is a lot of inserting and deleting from this table.

My problem is that somehow it seems to get corrupt I think because I am no longer able to select data past a certain point from a partition.

From cqlsh I can run soemthing like this.

SELECT accoutid,date,credit,debit,type FROM billing WHERE accountid=XXXXX-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx... AND date < 3d466d80-189c-11e7-8a57-f33cbced2fc5 limit 2;

First I did a select limit of 10000 it works up to around 5000 rows pageing through them then towards the end it will give a timeout error.

I then use the second from last timeuuid and select limit 2 it will fail limit 1 will work.

If I use the last timeuuid as a < and limit to 1 it will also fail.

So just looking for what I can do here I am not sure what is wrong and not sure how I can fix/diagnose what happened.

I have tired a repair and force a compaction.  but it still seems to have the issue.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses.   I found this link we kinda goes over in more detail about how I am using this table inside of cassandra and some options.  Generally I think all of you are correct that Tombstones are the issue.   Will try to comment back if that is no the case.  Here is the link I found.

https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/10/20/domain-modeling-around-deletes-or-using-cassandra-as-a-queue-even-when-you-know-better/

Comment: Yes thank you to all who replied definitely the result of too many Tombstones.

Answer (score 4):

1. Try to start with running manual compaction on your table.
2. You can increase **read_request_timeout_in_ms** parameter in cassandra config.
3. Consider moving to leveled compaction strategy if you are having a lot of deletes and updates.

Comment: thank you for the advice will try to see if that helps.  Yes there will be a lot of Deletes on the table.  I wonder if there is a way to set this table to have a different compaction schedule or some other thing for a table like this.  Currently the table is being used like a Queue.

Comment: There's parameters you can play with, both for STCS and LCS. Start with lowering thresholds for compaction trigers in STCS or small table size in LCS.

Comment: LeveldCompactionStrategy is better for this use case but it won't help if you got too many tombstones (more than 100 000)

Comment: Plus you must be careful when increasing read_request_timeout_in_ms, you run the risk of reaching the saturation point of your cluster.

Comment: @DineMartine "if you got too many tombstones (more than 100 000) " - why, if he tunes it to have small table size and low gc_grace?

Comment: @nevsv I mean too many tombstones in the same row/partition. I agree with you that low gc_grace will decrease the number of tombstones and that LCS is better to deal with tombstones.

Comment: @DineMartine Sure, you are right, about tombstones in 1 partition. That's why he should work with small sstable size (in LCS) and very aggressive gc_grace.

Answer (score 3):

I think you got too many tombstones in this partition.

**What is a tombstone ?**

To remember that a record has been deleted Cassandra creates a special value called a "tombstone". A tombstone has a TTL as any other value has but it is not compacted as easily as any other value is. Cassandra keeps it longer to avoid such inconsistency as data reappearence.

**How to watch tombstones ?**

*nodetool cfstats* gives you an idea of how many tombstones you have on average per slice

**How to fix the issue ?**

The duration a tombstone is preserved is *gc_grace_seconds*. You have to reduce it and then run a *major compaction* to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are hitting a lot of tombstones when you do selects. The thing is while they are there cassandra still has to go over them. There might be multiple factors like ttl with insert statements, a lot of deletes, inserting of nulls etc.

My bet would be that you would need to adjust gc_grace_seconds on table and run repairs more often. But be careful and don't set it to to low (one round of repair has to finish before this time).

It's all nicely explained here:
https://opencredo.com/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/